# Displacement Modifier and Texture Coordinates

Tags: modifiers

I am using a Displacement Modifier with an Image Texture.

Now in the Displacement Modifier panel you can chose the Texture Coordinates. On this page http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Displace I read that "Global – take the texture coordinates from the global coordinate system" and 
"Local – take the texture coordinates from the object’s local coordinate system". First, I don't understand what is meant with a local and global coordinate system but I guess since I am using a Texture Coordinate (generated) that I should chose LOCAL ??

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the newer manual: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html?highlight=displace   the one for version 2.4 is quite old and might not reflect the way newer versions of blender work.

Comment: related: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local is when you are using the object's own XYZ coordinates, regardless of it's placement in the global coordinates. For example, When you rotate an object in object mode the object will no longer be aligned with the world

[image]

Global has to do with the XYZ grid that starts in the origin 0,0,0. The transformations occur using the world's coordinates.

Here's a small example of how If your object is not aligned with the global coordinates you'll get different results using the displace modifier:

[image]

Comment: ok. So I guess I have to use the global coordinates.